# Scala Chart (JFreeChart) not working on AWS server

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Twitter bot (written in Scala) that I'm attempting to setup in an AWS server, running the Amazon Linux AMI.

The bot generates a chart, using [Scala Chart](https://github.com/wookietreiber/scala-chart) (which is a JFreeChart wrapper) and posts the chart to Twitter.

I've built the bot's executable file using SBT, and running it on my local machine works perfectly. However, when I run it on AWS, everything works except the chart generation. I don't get an error message until I try to post a link to a chart, when I find that the local file is non-existent.

I'm running a recent version of Java on ec2 (1.7.0._91), and can't think of what's going wrong.

Does AWS not allow background processes to generate images for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

No, your EC2 instance is yours to use as you please. But i'd guess that, being a headless server, it might be lacking the font or a graphical resource required by JFreeChart. Consider installing a desktop environment or testing in a graphic-less virtual machine.

Comment: I thought that everything needed by JFreeChart would be included in its JAR which is on the EC2 instance (along with everything needed by the bot).

Comment: May be, just guessing here, you can also try running your JVM in headless mode (-Djava.awt.headless=true) to confirm. Also, check that VM and libraries versions are the same as in local.